# Como moverse entre las ventanas de Visual Code con atajos de teclado

Tags: vscode

tengo el Visual Code dividido en tres (como también podría tenerlo dividido en muchas ventanas) como hago para moverme de una ventana a otra con algún atajo de teclado ? hasta ahora lo vengo haciendo con el mause pero es incomodo estar haciéndolo así cada ves que quiero escribir algo en al otra ventana,gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes moverte entre las ventanas que tengas con "ctrl + F1-F12", por ejemplo "ctrl + F1" te pondrá en la ventana 1, "ctrl + F2" en la ventana 2 y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso es <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> dependiendo de la ventana

Comment: Por si les sirve aquí les dejo la listaw de comandos: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf